# Page is returned before images are fetched

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I am trying to fetch images from this [website](https://swatmanga.me/1369517/my-school-life-pretending-to-be-a-worthless-person-13/)  but it is returned like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei84n.png)

the website is powered by wp-rocket if that would help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'if-modified-since': 'Tue, 06 Sep 2022 17:26:50 GMT',
    'referer': 'https://swatmanga.me/1369130/my-school-life-pretending-to-be-a-worthless-person-04/',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-gpc': '1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36'
}




link = 'https://swatmanga.me/1369130/my-school-life-pretending-to-be-a-worthless-person-04/'
video = requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=3)
print(video.text)
```

Comment: Can you share what the text content of video.text at the end? A screenshot is not sufficient to be able to understand the problem

Comment: There is nothing image-related in your code, and your screenshot just shows encoding-related mojibake, likely caused by a bad encoding guess by `video.text`. You should use `video.content` to get bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to understand how the page gets these images, in this case all images are initially available in the script tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get('https://swatmanga.me/1369517/my-school-life-pretending-to-be-a-worthless-person-13/', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
script_block = str([x for x in soup.find_all('script') if 'post_id' in x.get_text()][0])
script_block = script_block[script_block.find('(') + 1: script_block.rfind(')')]
for image in json.loads(script_block)['sources'][0]['images']:
    print(image)
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://i0.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_001-30.jpg
https://i3.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_002-30.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_003-30.jpg
https://i0.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_004-30.jpg
https://i2.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_005-30.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_006-30.jpg
https://i3.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_007-30.jpg
https://i3.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_008-30.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_009-29.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/a_010-29.jpg
https://i0.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_001-30.jpg
https://i3.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_002-30.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_003-30.jpg
https://i0.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_004-30.jpg
https://i2.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_005-30.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_006-30.jpg
https://i3.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_007-30.jpg
https://i3.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_008-30.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_009-29.jpg
https://i1.wp.com/swatmanga.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/b_010-29.jpg
```